# React: How to pass a pointer to one component to a second component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pointers, reference, components

How can you pass a pointer to component 1 to component 2 (so that you can work with component 1 inside component 2, e.g. get its properties)

```
<Component1 />
<Component2 target = {Component1} />
```

In part, this problem can be solved by handling events from component 1, because in this case a зpointer to it (event.target) will be available, but what about before such an event occurs?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're hoping to accomplish? Like "when such and such happens in `Component1` this is what I want to happen in `Component2`? I doubt your proposed method is viable, but there may be another way to achieve it.

Comment: @David784, Component1 - edit field, Component2 - panel with form. I want the panel to be glued to the field, so I need to somehow pass this field to the panel. A panel can be created/deleted (appear/disappear) depending on various conditions, often unrelated to the entry in the edit field, so it is not always possible to get the edit field through focus

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing throw props just import your component 1 in component2 if you want to use content of component1 in component2
and your good to go

Or if you what to use component2 as wrapper you can use children props

For example:

```js
function Component2(props) {
  return (
    <div className={'component2'}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Component2
```

and use it

```js
import Component2 from './component2'
import Component1 from './component1'
function App() {
  return (
    <Component2>
       <Component1/>
    </Component2>
  );
}
export default App
```

Comment: solution is interesting, but if Component2 is created dynamically (or at least becomes visible and invisible) depending on what happens to Component1, then this solution does not work - because Component1 will also be invisible :(